# Bbind a onclick function with object as parameter on anchor tag created in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, jquery-events

I am getting some JSON data and I am looping through it and for each data I am creating a Anchor tag and `onClick` of it I am trying to call a function with object as parameter.

Something like this:

```
$.getJSON('/ui_dashboard/rest/getAlertDefVsAlertValues',function(data) {    
        console.log(data)
        $("#checkAllAlertsTbody").empty();
        var mailServerTbody="";
        var objData = data.getAlertDefVsAlertValues;
        var objLen = objData.length;
        
        for(var i=0;i<objLen;i++){      
            //one object for all the key in the json 
            var alertWholeObject = {
                    alertFunctionId : objData[i].alertFunctionId,
                    alertMessage : objData[i].alertMessage,
                    definitionName:objData[i].definitionName,
                    emailMessage : objData[i].emailMessage,
                    emailSubject:objData[i].emailSubject,
                    emailTemplate : objData[i].emailTemplate,
                    hubId:objData[i].hubId,
                    id : objData[i].id,
                    isDefinitionEnabled:objData[i].isDefinitionEnabled,
                    mandatoryParam : objData[i].mandatoryParam,
                    scanInterval:objData[i].scanInterval,
                    smsMessage : objData[i].smsMessage,
                    smsTemplateId:objData[i].smsTemplateId,
                    tenantId : objData[i].tenantId,
                    timestamp:objData[i].timestamp,
                    list: objData[i].list,
                    isArray : function(what){
                        return Object.prototype.toString.call(what) === '[object Array]';
                    }
            };
        console.log(alertWholeObject.alertMessage)
            var idWithoutSpace = alertWholeObject.id.replace(/ /g, '');
            //for overview table
                mailServerTbody = '<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+alertWholeObject.definitionName+'</td><td>'+alertWholeObject.timestamp+'</td><td>'+
                '<div class="controls center">'+
                '<a class="btn btn-info btn-mini"  id="edit_'+idWithoutSpace+'" onclick="editAlertRules(' + alertWholeObject + ');"><i class="icon-edit icon-white">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i></a>'+
                '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" id="delete_'+idWithoutSpace+'" ><i class="icon-trash icon-white">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i></a>'+
                '</div></td></tr>'; 
            $("#checkAllAlertsTbody").append(mailServerTbody);
        }
        
    });
}
```

but the `onclick` function is not working; in console its showing only `[object object]`.

How do I send this object created in the loop to click of each anchor tag?

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Your logic seems to be flawed. `onclick="editAlertRules(' + alertWholeObject + ');"` will only result in a string literal. Moreover, once the anchor is inserted into the DOM, the object `alertWholeObject` will no longer be available!

Comment: @abhitalks how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**:

Sorry, I jumped the gun on this. Here is the update:

Do not pass the object as a parameter. Instead pass an index. Declare an Object array with an outer scope (or global scope).

```
var obj = [];
```

Inside your `for` loop instantiate an object in this array at the current index:

```
for (i=0; ....) {
    obj[i] = new Object;
...

}
```

Now, when you are specifying an inline `onclick`, just pass the index:

```
mailServerTbody = "... <a ... onclick='editAlertRules(" + i + ");'" ...</a>.."
```

Inside your function `editAlertRules` use the object in outer scope with index as the argument:

```
function editAlertRules(index) {

console.log(obj[index]);
...
}
```

Check this fiddle to get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/n8hSJ/1/

Hope that helps.

Comment: In this case too.All the a tag have click even with the last object generated in the loop as parameter.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha I have updated the answer. Sorry for missing the point earlier. +1 for the good question.

Comment: what If I dont want to use global variable. Can't it be done without the use of global variable. It is said that Its bad practice to use global variable.

Comment: Not necessarily a global. What is important is that variable should be at least in the same scope as that of your function `editAlertRules`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to bind to the click event. The function scope will make the right alertWholeObject available to the click callback. Add this code after you appended the HTML to your document.

```
$('#edit_' + idWithoutSpace).click(function () {
    editAlertRules(alertWholeObject);
});
```

Comment: in this case every time the last object is going into the function as parameter..

Comment: The code must be inside the loop (have overseen it in your code). Append on the end of the loop and use a DocumentFragment. Append the DocumentFragment after the loop to the document.

Comment: what do you mean by use a Document fragment after the loop can you please show with some example